# How can I use xargs to run a function in a command substitution for each match?

Tags: linux, bash, function, sed, xargs

While writing Bash functions for string replacements I have encountered a strange behaviour when using xargs. This is actually driving me mad currently as I cannot get it to work.
Fortunately I have been able to nail it down to the following simple example:

Define a simple function which doubles every character of the given parameter:

```
function subs { echo $1 | sed -E "s/(.)/\1\1/g"; }
```

Call the function:

```
echo $(subs "ABC")
```

As expected the output is:

```
AABBCC
```

Now call the function using xargs:

```
echo "ABC" | xargs -I % echo $(subs "%")
```

Surprisingly the result now is:

```
ABCABC
```

It seems as if the sed command inside the function treats the whole string now as a single character. 
Why does this happen and how can it be prevented?

You might ask, why I use xargs at all. Of course, this is a simplified example and the actual use case is much more complex.

In the original use case, I have a program which produces lots of output. I pipe the output through several greps to get the lines of interest. Afterwards, I pipe the lines to sed to extract the data I need from the lines. Because some transformations I need to do on the data are too complex to do with regular expressions alone, I'd like to use a function for these. So, my original idea was to simply pipe into the function but I couldn't get that to work and end up with the xargs solution. My original idea was something like this:

```
command | grep ... | grep ... | grep ... | sed ... | subs
```

BTW: I do not do this from the command line but from within a script. The function is defined in the very same script in which it is used.

I'm using Bash 3.2 (Mac OS X default), so fancy Bash 4.x stuff won't help me, sorry.

I'll be happy about everything which might shed some light on this topic.

Best regards

Frank

Comment: Keep in mind that xargs starts new subprocesses, **not running in the existing shell** (or any shell, unless you explicitly specify a command that will start one). Unless you jump through some hoops to do so, those subprocesses aren't shells at all.

Comment: ...and it helps to use `set -x` to log what's happening at the shell level, which would let you see the behavior described in choroba's answer.

Comment: (BTW, with respect to my suggestions that you probably really don't need to use xargs -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for guidance on looping over line-oriented input from native bash without using it).

Comment: Consider whether you actually *need* the command substitution. In this simple example, `... | xargs -I % subs %` would probably suffice.

Comment: @chepner, ...well, it would suffice if `subs` were an external program that could be `exec()`'d and not a function.

Comment: Of course the sane way to do this is simply `subs () { sed -E "s/(.)/\1\1/g" "$@"; }` and `echo "ABC" | subs`

Comment: @Charles Duffy, thanks for the -x switch, didn't know that.

Comment: Re: edit -- as I read it, you want `somecommand | grep ... | sed -E 's/(.)/\1\1/g'`, and have no need for a function at all. But that should really be its own question, not an edit to this one. (In *general*, we frown on edits to questions that invalidate existing answers after those answers have been added).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** need to do this (and you probably don't, but we can't help without a more representative sample), a better-practice approach might look like:

```
subs() { sed -E "s/(.)/\1\1/g" <<<"$1"; }
export -f subs

echo "ABC" | xargs bash -c 'for arg; do subs "$arg"; done' _
```

- The use of `echo "$(subs "$arg")"` instead of just `subs "$arg"` adds nothing but bugs (consider what happens if one of your arguments is `-n` -- and that's assuming a relatively tame `echo`; they're allowed to consume backslashes even without a `-e` argument and to do all manner of other surprising things). You *could* do it above, but it slows your program down and makes it more prone to surprising behaviors; there's no point.
- Running `export -f subs` export your function to the environment, so it can be run by other instances of bash invoked as child processes (all programs invoked by `xargs` are outside your shell, so they can't see shell-local variables or functions).
- Without `-I` -- which is to say, in its default mode of operation -- `xargs` appends arguments to the end of the command it's given. This permits a much more efficient usage mode, where instead of invoking one command per line of input, it passes as many arguments as possible to the shortest possible number of subprocesses.

  This also avoids major security bugs that can happen when using `xargs -I` in conjunction with `bash -c '...'` or `sh -c '...'`. (If you ever use `-I% sh -c '...%...'`, then your filenames become part of your code, and are able to be used in injection attacks on your system).

Comment: Thanks, this works. But you and others noted that I probably do not have to do this at all. I will add the actual use case to the original question and maybe someone can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I incorporated this solution into my script. It works and therefore I will mark this as solved. But I am still unhappy with starting a sub shell in xargs, because this requires me to export a lot of variables I actually do not really want to export. Is there any way to use this solution using the same shell?

Comment: If you want the same shell, you can't use xargs, period. Did you review the FAQ I previously linked (in one of the first comments on the question)? If all you want to do is run a segment of script based on content read from stdin, [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is the first place to start.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the construct `$(subs "%")` gets expanded by the shell when parsing the pipeline, so `xargs` runs with `echo %%`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to properly use the function from within the xargs expression without having it expanded while parsing the pipeline?

Comment: @Epiphastro, `$(...)` is a shell construct; it isn't run without a shell. Unless you run `xargs sh -c '...'` or `xargs bash -c '...'`, there *is* no shell started after xargs is, so those expansions can't be run *after* xargs figures out what your argument list is.