# How to extract code into a funciton when using xargs -P?

Tags: shell, sh, xargs

At fisrt,I have write the code,and it run well.

```
# version1
all_num=10
thread_num=5 
a=$(date +%H%M%S) 
seq 1 ${all_num} | xargs -n 1 -I {} -P ${thread_num} sh -c 'echo abc{}' 
b=$(date +%H%M%S) 
echo -e "startTime:\t$a"
echo -e "endTime:\t$b"
```

Now I want to  extract code into a funciton,but it was wrong,how to fix it?

```
get_file(i){
echo "abc"+i
 } 
all_num=10
thread_num=5 
a=$(date +%H%M%S) 
seq 1 ${all_num} | xargs -n 1 -I {} -P ${thread_num} sh -c "$(get_file {})"
b=$(date +%H%M%S) 
echo -e "startTime:\t$a"
echo -e "endTime:\t$b"
```

Comment: Don't ever use `-I {}` and `sh -c '...{}...'` in combination -- down that road lie shell injection vulnerabilities. Let xargs add contents to your shell's argument list, as it does by default without `-I`, and write your script to iterate over those arguments.

Comment: BTW, do you _really_ need this to be `/bin/sh`? It'd be a lot easier with bash.

Answer (score 1):

Because `/bin/sh` isn't guaranteed to have support for *either* printing text that when evaluates defines your function, or exporting functions through the environment, we need to do this the hard way, just duplicating the text of the function inside the copy of `sh` started by xargs.

Other questions already exist in this site describing how to accomplish this with bash, which is quite considerably easier. See f/e [How can I use xargs to run a function in a command substitution for each match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768307/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-run-a-function-in-a-command-substitution-for-each-match)

```
#!/bin/sh

all_num=10
thread_num=5 
batch_size=1  # but with a larger all_num, turn this up to start fewer copies of sh

a=$(date +%H%M%S) # warning: this is really inefficient
seq 1 ${all_num} | xargs -n "${batch_size}" -P "${thread_num}" sh -c '
  get_file() { i=$1; echo "abc ${i}"; }
  for arg do
    get_file "$arg"
  done
' _
b=$(date +%H%M%S)

printf 'startTime:\t%s\n' "$a"
printf 'endTime:\t%s\n' "$b"
```

---

Note:

- `echo -e` is not guaranteed to work with `/bin/sh`. Moreover, for a shell to be *truly compliant*, `echo -e` is required to write `-e` to its output. See [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).
- Putting `{}` in a `sh -c '...{}...'` position is a Really Bad Idea. Consider the case where you're passed in a filename that contains `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` -- it can't be safely inserted in an unquoted context, *or* a double-quoted context, *or* a single-quoted context, *or* a heredoc.
- Note that `seq` is also nonstandard and not guaranteed to be present on all POSIX-compliant systems. `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt "$all_num" ]; do echo "$i"; i=$((i + 1)); done` is an alternative that will work on all POSIX systems.

Comment: @KamilCuk, nope, `for arg do` is actually POSIX-compliant. I got that one wrong myself, and someone here corrected me with a link to the spec some years ago.

Comment: Och really? Och my. Well then, I have some spec reading to do! Thanks!

Comment: $(date +%H%M%S) # warning: this is really inefficient,What will be efficient way?@CharlesDuffy

Comment: @flower, well, with `/bin/sh` there is no efficient way, but with bash, `printf -v a '%(%H%M%S)T' -1` is the built-in equivalent to `a=$(date +%H%M%S)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I had to go look it up to refresh my memory -- in the grammar, see the very first option, `for_clause : For name do_group` -- though as of the current spec version, `For name sequential_sep do_group` is equally valid, so shells compliant with the 2018 version (at least) _are_ obligated to accept `for arg; do` even without an `in`.